# Where are my credentials being stored?

Tags: authentication, iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Seeing a strange issue where I am unable to log out of my account in the web app I'm building.

My authentication setup looks like this

#### Program.cs

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseHttpSys(options =>
    {
        options.Authentication.Schemes =
            AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
    })   
    .Build();
```

#### Startup.cs (in ConfigureServices)

```
services.AddAuthentication(
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

When I debug the application, it somehow always logs me in using the account **Bassie123**, but I want to change it to **Bassie**.

#### launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55680/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I cleared all my cookies, tried opening it in a private browsing window, and even republished the application to ISS, but still my credentials for **Bassie123** are being stored somewhere.

I know I could implement a logout method and call that, but this question is more about where the data is stored that is causing the account to persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the credentials were being stored in the winows **Credential Manager**.

They were sitting under **Windows Credentials -> http://addressofwebapp:3000**

After deleting the **Bassie123** credentials from there, the app now automatically logs me in as **Bassie**